# Inline variable in Haskell

Tags: haskell-mode, refactoring

Is there any way to inline a top-level definition or let binding in Haskell? I can't find any built-in solutions in vanilla haskell mode, HaRe, or Intero.

Comment: Maybe show an example of what you mean - what result you want, for what input? That might help others help you.

Comment: Hi Drew. Can you tell me what one might find ambiguous about this question? I will compose an example to target that ambiguity.

Comment: Maybe show before and after for a top-level definition or a let binding that you would expect to be inlined.